# How to change a CRUD-matrix into one using multi-index on columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a data structure like the one below, which mimics a CRUD matrix for processes and data objects:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'ObjA':'crud ru ru cu r'.split(), 
                 'ObjB':'r r ru rud crud'.split(), 
                 'ObjC':'d crud crud ru r'.split(),
                }, index='P1 P2 P3 P4 P5'.split())

df
```

This results in:

```
    ObjA  ObjB  ObjC
P1  crud     r     d
P2    ru     r  crud
P3    ru    ru  crud
P4    cu   rud    ru
P5     r  crud     r
```

I need to change this structure into one which uses indicator variables for c, r, u and d, so that the data objects (columns of the initial data structure) appear as level 0 and the crud-indicator variables as level 1 of a column multi-index, like shown here:

```py
df_dict={}

for col in df.columns:
    df_dict[col]=df[col].str.get_dummies('').reindex(columns='c r u d'.split())

pd.concat(df_dict, axis=1)
```

yielding:

```
   ObjA          ObjB          ObjC         
      c  r  u  d    c  r  u  d    c  r  u  d
P1    1  1  1  1    0  1  0  0    0  0  0  1
P2    0  1  1  0    0  1  0  0    1  1  1  1
P3    0  1  1  0    0  1  1  0    1  1  1  1
P4    1  0  1  0    0  1  1  1    0  1  1  0
P5    0  1  0  0    1  1  1  1    0  1  0  0
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the desired outcome apart from ugly iteration, building separate dataframes and then conatenating everything back into the final structure? I know there must be a way to do it with df.apply(some_clever_func, axis=) but my experiments so far all failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could not stop tinkering with it and finally came up with an even better solution, I believe:

```
(df
 .apply(lambda x: x.str.get_dummies(sep='').stack(), axis='columns')
 .reindex([*'crud'], level=1, axis='columns')
)
```

Although this is the slowest solution it is the one best readable. Funny enough, the solution in the question, using iteration, performs best.